# Partial permutations ways to arrange $3$ objects out of $5$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to select $3$ arrangements out of objects m,m,n,n,p?

I tried the partial permutation formula first $n!/(n-r)!$ and got 60, but then realized this had repeats in it. Such as counting $m,m$.  So I then tried to account for $m,m$ by finding 3 ways to organize $m,m$ and multiplying this by $2!$ (What's left from n,n,p where since n,n repeats we count it as $2!$).  I did the same with $n,n$ getting 6. Then I add this together and get a total of $12$ partial permutations. Any insights into of this is correct and of there's a better way when there are repeating elements. 
Thanks

Comment: If you fill two of the three positions with $m$'s, you have one place left to fill.  You have two ways to fill it, with $n$ or $p$.  It is not possible for $n$ to repeat since there is only one place left to fill.

Answer (score 2):

I count six arrangements that use both $m$s.  As you note, the "odd" letter can be either an $n$ or a $p$ (two choices) and it can go in any of three positions.

Similarly, there are six more arrangements that use both $n$s.

Finally, there are $3!=6$ arrangements of $m, n, p$ (the only way to avoid using a pair of letters), for a total of $18$.